# Too many connections with PDO persistent connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been struggling with this for quite a while, and it's to the point where I need to ask for help because even with all the research I've done I can't get a handle on why this is happening.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections'

This happens upon loading a single page (`index.php`), and I am the only user (dev). As you can see here, the MySQL connection limit is set @ 50 but I am narrowly surpassing that. This is an improvement over the 100~ connections that were being created before I refactored the code.

[image: MySQL connections before]

Here are the stats after the page has loaded once.

[image: MySQL connections after]

I've narrowed the issue down to several causes:

- I don't fully understand how PDO/MySQL connections work.
- I am creating too many connections in my code even though I am trying to only create one that I can share.
- I need to increase the connection limit (seems unlikely).

Most of the SO questions I've found, tell the OP to increase the connection limit without truly knowing if that's the best solution so I'm trying to avoid that here if it's not needed. 50 connections for one page load seems like way too many.

These are the classes I am instantiating on the page in question.

```
$DataAccess = new \App\Utility\DataAccess();
$DataCopyController = new App\Controllers\DataCopyController($DataAccess);
$DriveController = new App\Controllers\DriveController($DataAccess);
$Helper = new App\Utility\Helper();
$View = new App\Views\View();
```

I am creating the DAL object then injecting it into the classes that need it. By doing it this way I was hoping to only create one object and one connection, however this is not what's happening obviously. Inside the DAL class I've also added `$this->DbConnect->close()` to each and every query method.

Here is the constructor for the `DataAccess()` class.

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->DbConnect = new \App\Services\DbConnect();
    $this->db = $this->DbConnect->connect("read");
    $this->dbmod = $this->DbConnect->connect("write");

    $this->Helper = new Helper();
}
```

Here is the `DbConnect()` class.

class DbConnect {

```
  private $db;
  private $dbmod;

  private function isConnected($connection) {
    return ($connection) ? TRUE : FALSE;
  } 

  public function connect($access) {

    $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
                ];

    if ($access == "read") {
        if ($this->isConnected($this->db)) {
            return $this->db;
        } else {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], DBNAME_DEV) === false) {
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=".DBNAME, 
                                                                    DBUSER, 
                                                                    DBPASS, 
                                                                    $options
                                                                       );
            } else {
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST_DEV ."; dbname=".DBNAME_DEV, 
                                                                   DBUSER, 
                                                                   DBPASS, 
                                                                   $options
                                                                       );
            }
            return $this->db;
        }
    } elseif ($access == "write") {
        if ($this->isConnected($this->dbmod)) {
            return $this->dbmod;
        } else {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], DBNAME_DEV) === false) {
                $this->dbmod = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=".DBNAME, 
                                                                       DBUSER_MOD, 
                                                                       DBPASS, 
                                                                       $options
                                                                       );
            } else {
                $this->dbmod = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST_DEV . "; dbname=".DBNAME_DEV, 
                                                                       DBUSER_MOD, 
                                                                       DBPASS, 
                                                                       $options
                                                                       );
            }
        }
        return $this->dbmod;
    }
  }

  public function close() {
    $this->db = null;
    $this->dbmod = null;
  }
}
```

I've also tried instantiating the `DbConnect()` class on `index.php` and injecting that rather than `DataAccess()` but the result was the same.

**EDIT:**
I also want to add that this MySQL server has two databases, prod and dev. I suppose the connection limit is shared between both. However, the prod database gets very little traffic and I am not seeing this error there. When I refreshed the stats, there were no connections to the prod database.

Comment: From what I understand, you wouldn't want to close a persistent connection. Are you calling `DbConnect#close()` anywhere?

Comment: Also, from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/pdo.connections.php#example-1014) ~ _"If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in the array of driver options passed to the PDO constructor. If setting this attribute with PDO::setAttribute() after instantiation of the object, the driver will not use persistent connections."_

Comment: @Phil Thanks. So my persistent connection is not persistent. I will also try not closing the connections and let you know the result.

Comment: @Phil It worked! But there still seems to be something strange. On the mysql server I am seeing 20 persistent connections. 10 for the `db` instance and 10 for the `dbmod` instance.

Comment: I turned the persistent connections off, and am still seeing only 2 connections when the page loads. Seems closing the connections may have been the cause. Strange, but this is resolved. @Phil if you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the PHP manual ~ http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

> Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials.

So I would advise removing the `DbConnection#close()` method as you would not want to ever call this.

Also from the manual...

> **Note:**
>   If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set **`PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`** in the array of driver options passed to the `PDO` constructor. If setting this attribute with `PDO::setAttribute()` after instantiation of the object, the driver will not use persistent connections.

So you'll want (at least)

```
new \PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS, [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
]);
```

You can also set your other connection attributes in the constructor.

Comment: I ended up not being able to use persistent connections after all. There were so many as I mentioned because they appeared to be timing out and creating a new one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect they were all the connections living in the  _persistent connection cache_. Try clearing everything out first then see if they keep stacking

Comment: @Nick I can't seem to find any information on that. If PHP is running as an Apache module, I imagine the cache is tied to the Apache process. Restarting / reloading the web server should clear it out

Comment: @Phil no worries, thanks for looking. I've seen a similar issue and was wondering if that cache might be the reason for the numbers I am seeing. Restarting the server isn't really an option for me, and I want to persist :) with persistent connections as they give me a speed advantage.